# метод возвращающий экземпляр класса параметризованного типа

Tags: java, generics

Можно ли написать что-то наподобие?

```
<T> T metod(){
    T temp;
    cоздание и инициализация класса типа T
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: Прямо так - нет, поскольку во время выполнения недоступна информация о значении `T`. Ближе всего к желаемому - наследование от параметризованного класса с конкретным значением типа ([статья на хабре](https://habrahabr.ru/post/66593/))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Параметризованные методы в Java существуют, но напрямую, в лоб, создавать экземпляры типа-параметра они не могут. Это можно обойти либо передавая нужный класс в виде дополнительного параметра (как показал Senior Automator, см. также https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450807/how-do-i-make-the-method-return-type-generic), либо, в некоторых случаях, можно вручную проверять типы фактических параметров и создавать экземпляры конкретных типов. Вот пример кода, можете сами поиграться с ним:

```
public class TestGenericMethod {

  <T> T genericMerge(T a, T b) {
    System.out.printf("Inside method: %s, %s (class %s)\n", a, b, a.getClass());
    String s = a.toString() + b.toString();
    T result = (T)s;        // remains String
    System.out.printf("Result: %s of class %s\n", result, result.getClass());

    // T t = new T();       // нельзя 
    Object result2;          
    if (a.getClass().getName().contains("Integer"))
      result2 = Integer.valueOf(s); 
    else
      // В отличие от (T)result, приводит к нужному типу, но опасно
      result2 = a.getClass().cast(result); 
    System.out.printf("Result2: %s of class %s\n", result2,     result2.getClass());
    return (T)result2;
  }

  void run() {
    String s1 = "Строка 1 ", s2 = "Строка 2 ";
    Object o = genericMerge(s1, s2);
    System.out.printf("  genericMethod(%s, %s) = %s (%s)\n", s1, s2, o, o.getClass());
    Integer i1 = 5, i2 = 10;
    o = genericMerge(i1, i2);
    System.out.printf("  genericMethod(%s, %s) = %s (%s)\n", i1, i2, o, o.getClass());
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new TestGenericMethod().run(); 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно, но немного по-другому

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {

        MyClass3 metod = method(MyClass3.class);
        System.out.println(method.getAnyString());

    }

    private static <T> T method(Class<T> typeOfT) throws IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {
        PodamFactory factory = new PodamFactoryImpl(); // данная библиотека позволяет немного забыть о reflection 
        T myPojo = factory.manufacturePojo(typeOfT);
        return myPojo;
    }

    public class MyClass3 {

        public MyClass3() {
        }

        public String getAnyString(){
            return "blabla";
        }
    }

}

 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/uk.co.jemos.podam/podam -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>uk.co.jemos.podam</groupId>
        <artifactId>podam</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Результат

```
blabla

Process finished with exit code 0
```